# Excerpt_length nor the_excerpt not working correctly

Tags: excerpt

What I'm using-
WAMP, clean install of WordPress 4.3.1(No plugins) and starter theme - Underscore.

What I'm trying to achieve-
I want to have blog post, that shows only the excerpt, so I've modified content.php and change

```
<?php
        the_content( sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
            wp_kses( __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'cthulhu' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ),
            the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
        ) );
    ?>
```

to

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Now, I'm able to see my custom excerpt, but wordpress doesn't limit the lenght of excerpt - > I've puted 100 words to Excerpt and there's seems to be no limit in content (which should be 55 words by default).

I've also tried to add function to functions.php

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

it doesn't work.

I've also tried different themes - all version of Twenty- and it's still same.

Maybe I'm just to tired, but I'm struggling with this so hard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) ...

> Displays the excerpt of the current post after applying several
>   filters to it including auto-p formatting which turns double
>   line-breaks into HTML paragraphs. It uses `get_the_excerpt()` to first
>   generate a trimmed-down version of the full post content **should there
>   not be an explicit excerpt for the post.**

`get_the_excerpt()` [applies the `get_the_excerpt` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L373), to which `wp_trim_excerpt()` is [attached](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L144).

[If you look at that function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2797) you'll notice that `excerpt_length` is only applied when the excerpt is generated from the post body automatically. Otherwise, the manually written excerpt just passes straight through.

Honestly, since you are writing the excerpts I don't understand why you want to automatically truncate them, but if you must you can add a filter to `wp_trim_excerpt` using `wp_trim_excerpt()` as a model.

Comment: Alright, I've missunderstood the whole excerpt function.

Comment: The excerpt functionality is confusing.

Comment: Thank you, s_ha_dum♦, for bringing light to my path. Now I feel utterly stupid.
  
edit: I marked your answer as the right one, since it helped me to understand the basics of this functionality.